# Python: replace nested list with single digit

Tags: python, list, replace, nested-lists

Beginner's question.

I have the following ordered list with nested lists,

```
original_list=[['No', 'se', 'puede'], ['No', 'se', 'puede'], ['No', 'se', 'admiten']]
```

I would like to replace the nested list ['No', 'se', 'admiten'] by a single digit i.e. I want to obtain the following result,

```
required_list=[['No', 'se', 'puede'], ['No', 'se', 'puede'], 'i']
```

where i is any digit.

Since the actual original list is longer and contains more differing nested lists than the one I gave above, I want to replace the ['No', 'se', 'admiten'] by a "text recognising" command. Something like,

```
[if nested list contains 'No', 'se', 'admiten', replace by i]
```

such that I can replace any nested lists consisting out of any number of string elements by a single digit.

Comment: `original_list[-1] = 'i'`?

Comment: You need to clarify *what* you want to do and *why*. We need the context.

Comment: You're right. My bad. I've edited the question. Hopefully it's more clear now.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

List elements that are lists can be handled just like list elements that aren't lists, and finding and replacing a list element can be easily done using a [list comprehension](https://docs.python.org/3.6/tutorial/datastructures.html#list-comprehensions):

```
original_list=[['No', 'se', 'puede'], ['No', 'se', 'puede'], ['No', 'se', 'admiten']]
item_to_replace = ['No', 'se', 'admiten']

required_list = ['i' if x == item_to_replace else x for x in original_list]
```

Answer (score 0):

I guess you want to do this:

```
original_list=[['No', 'se', 'puede'], ['No', 'se', 'puede'], ['No', 'se', 'admiten']]

i = original_list[2]

original_list=[['No', 'se', 'puede'], ['No', 'se', 'puede'], i]
```

Comment: My apologies Ramesh, that is not exactly what I wanted. Nevertheless, thank you for thinking with me.  I realised that the original version of my question was lacking sufficient detail. I have elaborated a little on what I want.

Answer (score 0):

original_list=[['No', 'se', 'puede'], ['No', 'se', 'puede'], ['No', 'se', 'admiten']]

replace_value=['No', 'se', 'admiten']

for i,j in enumerate(original_list):

```
if replace_value == j:
    original_list[i] = 2
```

print original_list